# Android/Kotlin - Creating two buttons and applying constraints

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android/Kotlin, I would like to dynamically create two buttons and add constraints between boths (start/start and top/bottom).

I can constraint two static buttons :

```
    val mainLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.constraintLayout)
    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
    constraintSet.connect(b1.id, ConstraintSet.START, b2.id, ConstraintSet.END, 0)
    constraintSet.connect(b1.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, b2.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)
    constraintSet.applyTo(mainLayout)
```

but not while creating them dynamically : nothing appears on the screen.

In the dynamic case I noticed the ids where -1 for both ...

At the end, my goal is to dynamically create a grid of buttons.

Thanks !

Comment: `View`s don't have IDs by default. You need to assign them one when you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start from the end. if you want a grid view that contains buttons you must implement it by `RecyclerView`, anyway.

When you create a button, the button's id is -1. You can set an id into that by:

```
b1.id = View.generateViewId()
```

---

If you can't see buttons, check "Do you add buttons into mainView?" something like:

```
mainLayout.addView(b1)
```

Be careful you must add view before cloning `constraintLayout` into `ConstraintSet`.

Then I think your code will work!